# Android Convert Int to Hex Color

Tags: java, android, hex

How can I convert an int to a hex color and use it with a **ColorDrawable**?

I have tried other methods that use a string, and I get "ColorDrawable cannot be applied to java.lang.String".

I have tried:

```
String strColor = String.format("#%06X", 0xFFFFFF & actionColor);

actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(strColor));
```

But I cannot apply that to a ColorDrawable. I am trying to set the color of the ActionBar with hex.

Thanks

Comment: you can't create a ColorDrawable like that

Comment: Then how do I set the color of the ActionBar with hex? @Olayinka

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`ColorDrawable`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/ColorDrawable.html) takes an int as parameter not `string`. I suppose `actionColor` is also an integer (color hex) so you should do this.

```
int color = 0xFFFFFF & actionColor;
actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(color));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can think about a color as composed of 3 components. RGB. In your example you have 0xffffff. The first ff is the red component, the second ff is green component the third FF is the blue component. Change those hexadecimal values you can get your colors.

e.g. use

```
int color = Color.rgb(255, 255, 175);
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I am not fully understanding the question, but if I'm getting it correctly,
depending on your application purposes perhaps you could just use the int directly as follows:

```
   actionBar.setBackgroundColor(actionColor);
```

Assuming actionColor has the color you need, the function will take the int in its "hex form" and know what to do.